# Can I listen for Ag Grid events from outside angular

Tags: puppeteer, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, playwright

is it possible for me to listen for ag grid events like `filterChanged` or `modelUpdated` from outside angular?  For example, I'm using Playwright/Puppeteer and wanted to know when the grid is finished updated after filtering.